# Menú Expander en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, menú

Estoy intentando reproducir el funcionamiento del `Control Expander WPF`, o como se muestra en el menú del `Outlook`, `Menu Web Verticales` etc.,   ya que en `WindowsForms` no existe este control. Aquí dejo el [código de muestra : Menu_Expader.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gL9zhUVNUZb_aUhWxXxbkgOdJsGIs1RY/view?usp=sharing) enlace **GoogleDrive**.

**He logrado hacerlo usando los siguientes controles:**

- `Paneles`
- `FlowLayoutPanel`
- `1 Control Time`
- `Vectores de Botones`
- `Vectores de Labels` ...

> **Esto Funciona perfectamente**, pero sucede que a cada panel debo establecerle un `Tamaño Máximo` y `Tamaño Mínimo` por lo tanto cada vez que agrego un `item` dentro debo modificar el tamaño del panel donde lo agrego, y los `item` están muy pegados unos de otros es un poco molesto para la visión al usuario.

**Ejemplo esto es lo que tengo actualmente:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Editado:

**Ejemplo Mínimo:**

```
    private void Menu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        estructura_paneles();
    }

    //El estado de un panel de expandiendo o cerrando.
    private enum estado_expander
    {
        expandido,
        expansion,
        cerrando,
        cerrado,
    }

    //Paneles Expandidos en el Estado Actual.
    private estado_expander[] estados;

    // Paneles Expandidos y Cerrados.
    private Panel[] panel_expandido;

    //Botones expandidos y Cerrados.
    private Button[] botones_expanders;

    //Para iniciar los vectores, de los botones, labels, y demas. 
    //especificando, los paneles, botones y demas objetos. 
    private void estructura_paneles()
    {
        //Iniciar Vectores.
        estados = new estado_expander[]
        {
            estado_expander.expandido,
            estado_expander.expandido,
            estado_expander.expandido,
            estado_expander.expandido,
        };
        
        panel_expandido = new Panel[]
        {
            panel_modulo1, //indice 0
            panel_modulo2, //indice 1
            panel_modulo3, //indice 2
            panel_modulo4, //indice 3
        };

        botones_expanders = new Button[]
        {
            boton_modulo1, //indice 0
            boton_modulo2, //indice 1
            boton_modulo3, //indice 2
            boton_modulo4, //indice 3
        };

        // Expandir Botones, dar indice y Asignar imagenes a los Botones
        //Se capturan la cantidad de botones y se recorre para asignarle el indice, 
        //de modo que puedan hacer el expander. 
        for (int indice = 0; indice < botones_expanders.Length; indice++)
        {
            botones_expanders[indice].Tag = indice;
            botones_expanders[indice].Image = Properties.Resources.abajo;
        }
    }

    private void boton_expander_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button boton = sender as Button;
        int indice = (int)boton.Tag;

        estado_expander estado_viejo = estados[indice];
        if ((estado_viejo == estado_expander.cerrado) ||
            (estado_viejo == estado_expander.cerrando))
        {
            estados[indice] = estado_expander.expansion;
            botones_expanders[indice].Image = Properties.Resources.arriba;
        }
        else
        {
            estados[indice] = estado_expander.cerrando;
            botones_expanders[indice].Image = Properties.Resources.abajo;
        }
        tiempo_expandir.Enabled = true;
    }

    // Numero de Pixeles Expandidos por La Herramienta Timer Tick.
    private const int tiempo_expansion = 20;

    private void tiempo_expandir_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool no_ejecutado = false;

        for (int indice = 0; indice < panel_expandido.Length; indice++)
        {
            if (estados[indice] == estado_expander.expansion)
            {
                Panel panel = panel_expandido[indice];
                int nueva_altura = panel.Height + tiempo_expansion;

                if (nueva_altura >= panel.MaximumSize.Height)
                    nueva_altura = panel.MaximumSize.Height;
                else
                    no_ejecutado = true;
                panel.Height = nueva_altura;
            }
            else if (estados[indice] == estado_expander.cerrando)
            {
                Panel panel = panel_expandido[indice];
                int nueva_altura = panel.Height - tiempo_expansion;

                if (nueva_altura <= panel.MinimumSize.Height)
                    nueva_altura = panel.MinimumSize.Height;
                else
                    no_ejecutado = true;
                panel.Height = nueva_altura;
            }
        }
        tiempo_expandir.Enabled = no_ejecutado;
    }
```

**Quiero lograr algo como esto - Bootstrap Menu Accordion:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Imitar ese funcionamiento que **los paneles se expandan según la `cantidad` de `item`que este contenga** mientras no sobresalga de la pantalla, en dado caso mostrar la `barra de desplazamiento` . Se que existen software que brindan controles personalizados como `DVexpress`, `DotNetBar Suite` entre otros, pero son `Software Licenciados` no quiero usarlo de forma ilícita `pirata`.  **¿Pueden ayudarme a optimizarlo o crear esto de otra forma?**

Entorno: Visual Studio 2010 & .NET NetFramework 4.

**Nota:** Disculpen la publicidad en la imagen, grabé la pantalla con un software versión de prueba.

Comment: No has pensado en utilizar alguna librería de terceros que haga todo esto por ti? Normalmente para estas cosas alguien ya ha pasado antes por ahí. Un ejemplo: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JohannGranados.CollapsiblePanelforWindowsForms

Comment: @Corpex ,Le estoy dando un vistazo a tu sugerencia, pero igual veo que utiliza los espacios de los paneles semejante al mio. En mi pregunta he puesto que se que existen `librerias de terceros`, pero las mayoría son de software con licencias. Si fuera para mi uso personal las podría usar, pero cuando se trata de un uso comercial no se puede usar pirateado.

Comment: @Corpex Aunque el link que me pasas no es exactamente el resultado que necesito, me ha parecido bien el ejemplo del link, intentaré adaptarlo a mi necesidad.