# Consulta por componente para Visual Studio con c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017

Tengo una aplicación hecha en c# con Windows Forms.

Quisiera saber si esto se puede hacer, voy a poner una foto para que se entienda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He visto varias paginas que, en la sección de preguntas, estas las tienen encerradas en, por decirle de alguna forma, botones, los cuales al dar click se despliegan hacia abajo y muestran la respuesta y si les das click nuevamente guardan este texto.

He estado buscando en internet pero no he visto nada parecido, sé que existen los tabs pero no es lo que busco.

Se puede hacer algo parecido en C#, quizás visualmente no sea igual pero si la funcionalidad??

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Que tipo de proyecto estas creando, es winform, wpf, web con asp.net, asp.net mvc, etc ? porque mencionar solo c# es muy generico, con C# podras hasta programar mobile con Xamarin, o video juegos con Unity 3D

Comment: perdón, es un windows form. Actualicé la pregunta para que quede más claro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí te dejo este [Panel plegable para formularios de Windows](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JohannGranados.CollapsiblePanelforWindowsForms), además puedes modificar su apariencia a tu gusto con un poco de esfuerzo, es un código bastante entendible.

Me parece que puede ayudarte con tu lo que necesitas, ademas puedes darle un vistazo esta pregunta: [Menú Expander en C#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/130384/men%c3%ba-expander-en-c) que realizé hace mucho tiempo donde tengo un proyecto de muestra que puede servirte.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sirva.
Saludos!

Comment: esto está mucho mejor, porque mi idea es despues agregarle campos de texto y labels. Muchas Gracias. pd: podría, en caso de, pedirte ayuda cuando esté realizando esta ventana?

Comment: Me alegra que haya sido de utilidad, si tienes alguna duda en lo adelante la preguntas

Answer (score 1):

El componente que buscas se llama Expand Panel en WPF, existe algo similar para Windows Forms

Mira este componente para Windows Forms `Control Expander`

- [Github del control alexander-makarov/ExpandCollapsePanel](https://github.com/alexander-makarov/ExpandCollapsePanel)

En general, es básico pero funciona.

Permite editar en vista de Form Designer
Permite manejo de Layouts en la región de contenido
Permite editar tamaños y estilos look and feel.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: .. no me aparece cuando lo busco en el cuadro de herramientas

Comment: Tienes que descargarlo desde el link y agregarlo al cuadro de herramientas.

Comment: Tienes que entrar al enlace y descargarte el proyecto, no es nativo de .net winforms, luego lo compilas y adicionas la dll a tu proyecto